# What are the expected values for the various "ENUM" types returned by the SurveyMonkey API?

Tags: surveymonkey

There are multiple endpoints which return "ENUM" types, such as:

- the ENUM-integer `language_id` field from [the `get_survey_list`](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list) and [the `get_survey_details`](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details) endpoints
- the String-ENUM `type` field from [the `get_collector_list` endpoint](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_collector_list)
- the String-ENUM `collection_mode` and `status` fields from [the `get_respondent_list` endpoint](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list)

I understand what this means but I don't see the possible values documented anywhere. So, to repeat the title: what are the possible values for each of these enums?

Comment: Also we've got some changes in the works to make this much easier to find, i.e. clickable links from the method documention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language_id, status and collection_mode enums are documented here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/data_types

The String-ENUM `type` field from [the `get_collector_list` endpoint](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_collector_list):

**Collector Types**

```
url             Url Collector
embedded        Embedded Collector
email           Email Collector
facebook        Facebook Collector
audience        SM Audience Collector
```

The String-ENUM `collection_mode` and `status` fields from [the `get_respondent_list` endpoint](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list):

**Respondent Collection Modes**

```
normal          Collected response online
manual          Admin entered response in settings
survey_preview  Collected response on a preview screen
edited          Collected via a edit to a previous response
```

**Respondent Statuses**

```
completed   Finished answering the survey
partial     Started but did not finish answering the survey
```

The ENUM-integer `language_id` field from [the `get_survey_list`](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list) and [the `get_survey_details`](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details) endpoints:

**Language Ids**

```
1   English
2   Chinese(Simplified)
3   Chinese(Traditional)
4   Danish
5   Dutch
6   Finnish
7   French
8   German
9   Greek
10  Italian
11  Japanese
12  Korean
13  Malay
14  Norwegian
15  Polish
16  Portuguese(Iberian)
17  Portuguese(Brazilian)
18  Russian
19  Spanish
20  Swedish
21  Turkish
22  Ukrainian
23  Reverse
24  Albanian
25  Arabic
26  Armenian
27  Basque
28  Bengali
29  Bosnian
30  Bulgarian
31  Catalan
32  Croatian
33  Czech
34  Estonian
35  Filipino
36  Georgian
37  Hebrew
38  Hindi
39  Hungarian
40  Icelandic
41  Indonesian
42  Irish
43  Kurdish
44  Latvian
45  Lithuanian
46  Macedonian
47  Malayalam
48  Persian
49  Punjabi
50  Romanian
51  Serbian
52  Slovak
53  Slovenian
54  Swahili
55  Tamil
56  Telugu
57  Thai
58  Vietnamese
59  Welsh
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so as well as Miles' answer may I offer this list mapping the types to the Qtype in the Relational Database format, as we are transitioning from that. The list is mapped to SM's ResponseTable.html but that file does not give Qtype 160, or 70 which I guess is the ranking one.

```
    Question Family Question Subtype    QType 
single_choice   vertical    10
    vertical_two_col    11
    vertical_three_col  12
    horiz   13
    menu    14
multiple_choice     vertical    20
    vertical_two_col    21
    vertical_three_col  22
    horiz   23
matrix  single  30
    multi   40
    menu    50
    rating  60
    ranking     
open_ended  numerical   80
    single  90
    multi   100
    essay   110
demographic     us  120
    international   130
datetime    date_only   140
    time_only   141
    both    142
presentation    image   
    video   
    descriptive_text    160
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify? Which format are you transitioning from?

Comment: Relational Database export. This gives a zip file with a folder with some documentation in html format eg that ResponsesTable.html referred to above, and two subfolders, \Excel with a set of XLS files and \CSV with csv files. We used it because it gave us a normalised set of data - Survey, Pages, Collectors, Questions, QuestionOptions, Responses, and ResponsesText. That format is now retired by SM but because we have so much code that uses it, I now added code to download the json data and save it in that format.