# surveymonkey Where is qtype and respondent_id in the get_survey_details extract?

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm trying to replicate the survey monkey relational database format (A relational database view of your data with a separate file created for each database table. Knowledge of SQL (Structured Query Language) is necessary.) to download responses for our reporting analytics using the Survey Monkey API. However I'm not able to find the QType and respondent_id data in the get_survey_details API extract method. Can someone help?

1.QType is found in the Questions.xls data in the current relational database format download.

I was able to find all of the other data in the Questions.xls data in the get_survey_details API (question_id, page_id, position, heading) but not QType.

2.Respondent_id is found in the Responses.xls data in the the relational database format download.

I can see that respondent_id is in the get_responses API method but that does not have the associated Key1 data that I also need. Key1 data is answer_id data in the get_survey_details API which is why I expected to find the corresponding respondent_id there as well.

Answer (score 0):

SurveyMonkey's deprecated relational database download (RDD) format and API provide data using very different paradigms. Using the API to recreate the RDD format in order to work with an old integration is probably a poor use of time. A more productive idea would be to use the API to build a more modern integration from the ground-up taking advantage of things like real-time data availability to modernize the functionality. But if you're determined:

You will need to map the family and subtype of the question type to the QTypes you're used to. The information you need to build the mapping can be found on SurveyMonkey's developer portal in [Data Types](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/data_types).

`get_responses` returns `answer_id` as `row` and/or `col`. For matrix question types, you will have both which cross reference to and answer and answer items from `get_survey_details`. For matrix questions, you might consider concatenating the `row` and `col` to create a single unique key value like the Key1 you're accustomed to.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this. It got over the immediate need when the RDD format was withdrawn.
Now that I have more time, I'm looking at a better design but as always backwards compatibility with a large code base is the drag.

To answer your question on Qtype, see my reply at

[What are the expected values for the various "ENUM" types returned by the SurveyMonkey API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418918/what-are-the-expected-values-for-the-various-enum-types-returned-by-the-survey)