# Making Sense of the SurveyMonkey API JSON data returned from get_responses

Tags: java, json, surveymonkey

I am tasked with creating a very similar output to the excel output that is generated from the SurveyMonkey application.  Most of the answer-to-answer mapping is pretty straight forward, but mapping matrix type questions seems overly complicated.  Has anyone come up with a reliable way to map this data in order to export it to a list-based response?  The best thing I have come up with is building an in-memory tree mapping the collectors to respondents to questions to answers to (selected) answers.

To me, this seems like a lot of unnecessary mapping, and I'm just wondering if anyone has come up with a better way.

Answer (score 1):

See the related question:
[What are the expected values for the various "ENUM" types returned by the SurveyMonkey API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418918/what-are-the-expected-values-for-the-various-enum-types-returned-by-the-survey?rq=1)

I give a lot of skeleton VBA code at
[Accessing SurveyMonkey API from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366206/accessing-surveymonkey-api-from-vba/29794918#29794918)

Good luck
Patrick